# How to retrieve tweets by screenName via the twitter api so that I can get tweet created date, tweet and tweet media?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, twitter, endpoint

I've been looking at the twitter api calls and I was going to use

[https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name="](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=%22) + TwitterProfile

Just wondering what endpoint should I be using if I want to retrieve
tweet created date, tweet and media(if there is an image in the tweet)

by screenName ?

The above doesnt seem to contain tweet media, it only contains the tweet created on and tweet.

Is this the correct version of the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `tweet_mode=extended` you should get the media information as well - it sounds like this is an extended 140+ character Tweet, which is truncated by default.